# Financial graph LaTeX style

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, graphs

I am used to work with LaTex, but I am totally stuck trying to plot the following graph and include it in my paper using a LaTex layout.

[image: Uber, GM, Ford Value]

Here below I am also reporting the dataset (markdown does not support tables):

```
Date    Ford    GM      Uber
2010 Q4 60.000  50.000  0,01
        70.000  57.000  0,01
        60.000  55.000  0,01
2011 Q2 55.000  47.000  0,01
        56.000  45.000  0,01
        58.000  45.500  0,01
        56.000  44.500  0,01
        52.000  44.000  0,01
2011 Q4 39.000  38.000  0,01
        43.000  42.000  0,01
        41.000  40.000  0,01
        41.000  39.000  0,01
        47.000  44.000  0,01
2012 Q2 48.000  45.000  0,01
        47.000  44.000  0,01
        47.000  45.000  0,500
        40.000  38.000  0,501
        39.000  35.000  0,502
2012 Q4 37.000  33.000  0,503
        36.000  30.000  0,504
        38.000  32.000  0,505
        40.000  33.000  0,506
        44.000  34.000  0,507
2013 Q2 48.000  39.000  0,508
        53.000  44.000  0,509
        51.000  41.000  0,510
        53.000  44.000  0,511
        67.000  55.000  0,512
2013 Q4 65.000  52.000  0,513
        69.000  57.000  0,514
        68.000  56.000  0,515
        65.000  51.000  3000
        62.000  48.000  3000
2014 Q2 60.000  50.000  3000
        55.000  44.000  18.000
        60.000  50.000  18.000
        58.000  48.000  18.000
        56.000  47.000  18.000
2014 Q4 55.000  50.000  18.000
        65.000  60.000  18.000
        64.000  58.000  41.000
        62.000  55.000  41.500
        60.000  58.000  42.000
2015 Q2 58.000  56.000  42.000
        52.000  48.000  42.500
        59.000  48.000  52.500
        58.000  45.000  52.500
        57.000  55.000  52.500
2015 Q4 56.000  57.000  62.500
```

I know that there are manuals for TikZ and PGF plots, but the deadline is coming.

Comment: Can you transpose your data as columns and paste it as a code ? If you select your data and click `{}` in the edit menu it marks it as a code and we can copy paste it.

Comment: Where's the other set of coordinates? You're only giving the Y coordinates.

Comment: Done @percusse hope now is more useful.

Comment: @Alenanno Excel does not need the exact coordinates, it used the data available and interpolate the others missing. I can provide full coordinates if it could help

Comment: Ok,  I never used Excel like that,  but as far as I know  `pgfplots` needs two set of coordinates. I never saw a plot with only one set, so if you could add them,  it'd help, thanks.

Comment: Actually, this graph does not make any sense, because Ford and GM sell cars, whereas Uber sells transportation service.  They have inherently different business models (I'm not an economist, it's just what I noticed).

Comment: @HenriMenke It's about valuation of the companies not products.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should give you a starting point.  If you have any questions, consult the [`pdfplots` user guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Date,    Ford,   GM,     Uber
2010 Q4 3, 60000, 50000, 1
2010 Q4 4, 70000, 57000, 1
2010 Q4 5, 60000, 55000, 1
2011 Q2 1, 55000, 47000, 1
2011 Q2 2, 56000, 45000, 1
2011 Q2 3, 58000, 45500, 1
2011 Q2 4, 56000, 44500, 1
2011 Q2 5, 52000, 44000, 1
2011 Q4 1, 39000, 38000, 1
2011 Q4 2, 43000, 42000, 1
2011 Q4 3, 41000, 40000, 1
2011 Q4 4, 41000, 39000, 1
2011 Q4 5, 47000, 44000, 1
2012 Q2 1, 48000, 45000, 1
2012 Q2 2, 47000, 44000, 1
2012 Q2 3, 47000, 45000, 500
2012 Q2 4, 40000, 38000, 501
2012 Q2 5, 39000, 35000, 502
2012 Q4 1, 37000, 33000, 503
2012 Q4 2, 36000, 30000, 504
2012 Q4 3, 38000, 32000, 505
2012 Q4 4, 40000, 33000, 506
2012 Q4 5, 44000, 34000, 507
2013 Q2 1, 48000, 39000, 508
2013 Q2 2, 53000, 44000, 509
2013 Q2 3, 51000, 41000, 510
2013 Q2 4, 53000, 44000, 511
2013 Q2 5, 67000, 55000, 512
2013 Q4 1, 65000, 52000, 513
2013 Q4 2, 69000, 57000, 514
2013 Q4 3, 68000, 56000, 515
2013 Q4 4, 65000, 51000, 3000
2013 Q4 5, 62000, 48000, 3000
2014 Q2 1, 60000, 50000, 3000
2014 Q2 2, 55000, 44000, 18000
2014 Q2 3, 60000, 50000, 18000
2014 Q2 4, 58000, 48000, 18000
2014 Q2 5, 56000, 47000, 18000
2014 Q4 1, 55000, 50000, 18000
2014 Q4 2, 65000, 60000, 18000
2014 Q4 3, 64000, 58000, 41000
2014 Q4 4, 62000, 55000, 41500
2014 Q4 5, 60000, 58000, 42000
2015 Q2 1, 58000, 56000, 42000
2015 Q2 2, 52000, 48000, 42500
2015 Q2 3, 59000, 48000, 52500
2015 Q2 4, 58000, 45000, 52500
2015 Q2 5, 57000, 55000, 52500
2015 Q4 1, 56000, 57000, 62500
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=15cm,height=8cm,
    symbolic x coords = { 2010 Q4 3,2010 Q4 4,2010 Q4 5,
      2011 Q2 1,2011 Q2 2,2011 Q2 3,2011 Q2 4,2011 Q2 5,
      2011 Q4 1,2011 Q4 2,2011 Q4 3,2011 Q4 4,2011 Q4 5,
      2012 Q2 1,2012 Q2 2,2012 Q2 3,2012 Q2 4,2012 Q2 5,
      2012 Q4 1,2012 Q4 2,2012 Q4 3,2012 Q4 4,2012 Q4 5,
      2013 Q2 1,2013 Q2 2,2013 Q2 3,2013 Q2 4,2013 Q2 5,
      2013 Q4 1,2013 Q4 2,2013 Q4 3,2013 Q4 4,2013 Q4 5,
      2014 Q2 1,2014 Q2 2,2014 Q2 3,2014 Q2 4,2014 Q2 5,
      2014 Q4 1,2014 Q4 2,2014 Q4 3,2014 Q4 4,2014 Q4 5,
      2015 Q2 1,2015 Q2 2,2015 Q2 3,2015 Q2 4,2015 Q2 5,
      2015 Q4 1},
    xtick = {2010 Q4 3,2011 Q2 1,2011 Q4 1,2012 Q2 1,2012 Q4 1,2013 Q2 1,2013 Q4 1,2014 Q2 1,2014 Q4 1,2015 Q2 1,2015 Q4 1},
    xticklabels = {2010 Q4,2011 Q2,2011 Q4,2012 Q2,2012 Q4,2013 Q2,2013 Q4,2014 Q2,2014 Q4,2015 Q2,2015 Q4},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    ytick={0,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000},
    ylabel={Valuation (in \$\ Million)},
    every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
    no marks,
    grid=major,
    legend pos=south east,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={draw=none,fill=none},
    ]
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\loadedtable
    \addplot table[x=Date,y=Ford] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot table[x=Date,y=GM] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot table[x=Date,y=Uber] {\loadedtable};
    \legend{Ford,General Moters,Uber}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]